# Test for invalid value errors for SVG Elements in React with jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, svg, jestjs

To test my react app, I'm trying to catch all errors that are thrown or written to console.

If a normal HTML element like `<p>` has invalid attributes like `<p color={false}></p>` react prints a error over `console.error`, which I can test like this (I'm using jest with enzyme):

```
it("renders without error", () => {

    jest.spyOn(console, "error");

    mount(<p color={true}>asdf</p>);

    expect(console.error).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Now if I want to test for invalid values in an SVG element like this:

```
<svg>
    <rect width={-1}/>
</svg>
```

My test won't work, because the error is not printed using `console.error` and I can't get behind what is printing it.

To reproduce the errors, the console output on this fiddle can be checked: https://jsfiddle.net/uu1j4ksa/

Any good ideas on how errors like this should be tested?

Comment: Could you try `jest.spyOn(global.console, "error");`

Comment: Didn't work for me. What's different between `jest.spyOn(console, "error");` and `jest.spyOn(global.console, "error");`?

Comment: `global.console`is the one that is used in the context of the module, the other on is the one from the test itself. Btw it should be `global.console = {error: jest.fn()}` and then `expect(global.console.error).toHaveBeenCalled()`

Answer (score 0):

You can set the console in your module to test via the `global` context

```
global.console = {error: jest.fn(), log: jest.fn()}
```

test looks like this:

```
expect(global.console.error).toHaveBeenCalled()
```